# How some functions can self provide needed parameters to work in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

There are some kind of protocols in SwiftUI which they have a function, that `struct` should have same function to be able to conform to that protocol,

like **ViewModifier** protocol which need

`func body(content: Content) -> some View { return content }`

or **Shape** protocol which need

`func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path { return Path { path in } }`

When we are using those **struct** that conform to these protocols, we actually does not provide any parameters to those required functions from protocol, they grab there need parameters magically from context.

***Which this auto grab parameters is big question for me how this process happens?***

There for I re created **Shape** protocol to actually try and test this auto grab feature! How can my function automatically grab needed parameters! Right now my code is not grabbing need data, instead of returning **Shape**, it returns **View**! which I did all the things the same like apple done! why **Shape** protocol of apple returns **Shape** but my protocol does not, also my functions does not auto grab the needed data.

---

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {

        CustomShape() // print: CustomShape: (0.0, 0.0, 414.0, 405.0) without body of CustomShape: Shape!
            
     
        CustomSHAPE() // it does not print! But also returns unwished View!
        
    }
}
```

---

```
struct CustomShape: Shape {
    
    //var body: some View { Color.blue } // if we have body, path would stop working!
    
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        print("CustomShape:", rect)
        
        return Path { path in }
        
    }
  
}


protocol SHAPE: Animatable, View { }

struct CustomSHAPE: SHAPE {
    
    var body: some View { Color.red } // if we have body, path would stop working! also I cannot comment it like we can in CustomShape: Shape

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        
        print("CustomSHAPE:", rect)
        
        return Path { path in }
        
    }
  
}
```

Comment: I posted and then deleted an answer because I realized you were asking a different question that I originally thought.

Comment: @ChipJarred: thanks for your help, I am asking for auto grab parameters functionality and how can I recreate it like in **SHAPE** for grabbing needed data

Comment: I posted a new, updated answer, but it might be more helpful to know more precisely you're trying to achieve.  There may be a solution for that particular problem that isn't obvious from the general question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't need magic for your protocol to be able to "auto grab" stuff. You can set default values for a protocol's declarations by using `extension`s. Here is a simple example:

An example without "auto grab":

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func doSomething() -> Bool
}

// ERRORRRR! MyStructure doesnt conform to MyProtocol because you havent defined
// the required function `func doSomething() -> Bool`
struct MyStructure: MyProtocol {
    
}
```

An example with "auto grab":

```
protocol MyProtocol {
    func doSomething() -> Bool
}

extension MyProtocol {
    func doSomething() -> Bool {
        print("Im doing all i can!")
        return false
    }
}

// No Errors because `func doSomething() -> Bool` has defaulted to the func
// that we declared in `extension MyProtocol`. so it "auto grab" the default func.
struct MyStructure: MyProtocol {
    
}
```

Remember this was only a simple example. You can do much more complicated "auto grab"s using the power of extensions.

This is almost what is happening in `Shape`. Apple engineers have defined a default `var body: some View` for any `Shape`:
[image]
When you declare your own `var body: some View` in a type that conforms to `Shape`, you are overriding the default `var body` that Apple engineers have defined, with your insufficient `var body` that doesnt contain anything much.

I haven't digged into it but there is a chance that the `_ShapeView<Self, ForegroundStyle>` that you can see in the picture does do some actual wizardry by accessing stuff that are internal and we don't have access to yet.

EDIT:
All that being said, i digged into this more as i was curious, and here's a working example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        CustomShape()
        CustomSHAPE()
    }
}

struct CustomShape: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        print("CustomShape:", rect)
        return Path { path in }
    }
}

protocol SHAPE: Animatable, View {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path
}

extension SHAPE {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            self.path(in: geo.frame(in: .local))
        }
    }
}

struct CustomSHAPE: SHAPE {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        print("CustomSHAPE:", rect)
        return Path { path in }
    }
}
```

in console you'll see something like this printed:

```
CustomShape: (0.0, 0.0, 390.0, 377.66666666666663)
CustomSHAPE: (0.0, 0.0, 390.0, 377.5)
```

Comment: I already defined a simple example, need to work with that, I mean **SHAPE** protocol

Comment: You commented in less that a minute or two after i posted the answer which makes me think you haven't even read the answer well since `extension` on top of protocols is not that easy to digest. Im explaining a general concept to you so you can rename `MyProtocol` to `SHAPE` if you want.

Comment: No, I made a question and created an simple example need to work with it for me.

Comment: your answer is not solving any issue for me, thanks any way

Comment: I looked into making the exact same thing that `Shape` protocol has but i can't do it without making a custom `_ShapeView<Self, ForegroundStyle>` which needs `Self` to conform to `SHAPE` not `Shape`. As its apparent from the `_` behind `_ShapeView`, the `_ShapeView` is something internally-used by Apple engineers and i can't remake something like `_ShapeView` for `SHAPE` without knowing how Apple has implemented it for their own `Shape`.

Comment: Here you go. Note that there is no guarantee that this works as good as the original Apple Shape does even for basic shapes, specially since i didn't remake the `_ShapeView`, but it does work as you wanted it.

Comment: That is obvious GeometryReader would gave the needed value, I was using this before asking the question! Shape from apple does not use GeometryReader! It use other way. remember the question was about auto grab parameters! where is auto in your code?

Comment: How do you know it doesnt use Geometry Reader?!? If you ask me i'd say that that even Apple does use Geometry Reader. Not sure what's wrong with using Geometry Reader.

Comment: I have nothing against your thinking or code unless I use Shape protocol and I see just a func and I see no GeometryReader there.

Comment: You CANT see how a func works in DOCUMENTATION. Documentation EXCLUDES all/almost-all closures. The fact that there is nothing there has nothing to do with the actual way Apple engineers have implemented `Shape`.

Comment: Then there is no auto grabbing data, maybe apple gave need parameters to function in extension like you did! right?

Comment: YES! Apple engineers have done somewhat the same thing i've done here, its just you can't see those stuff in Documentation because Documentation always excludes these kind of things.

Comment: Happy to actually have helped someone although it was a little bit though (LOL). These stuff are not the easiest things to digest/understand and thats a nice achievement for me to actually have helped someone learn these in such (relatively) short conversation.

Comment: In the fact I was using GeometryReader  before asking my question!  And Since I saw no GeometryReader in Apple Shape, I thought about auto grabbing data, but you showed a way in Extension! Which changed the all things!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem comes down thinking in terms of "auto grabbing parameters."

The `Shape` protocol is where `path(in:)` is declared for `SwiftUI`.  `View` "knows" that any type conforming to `Shape` provides a `path(in:)` method that it can call with the bounds of the view into which it wants to render the shape.

Your `CustomShape` isn't auto-grabbing anything. It conforms to `Shape` so `View` calls its `path(in:)`.  Under the hood, hidden away from from us mere mortals who don't work at Apple, there is an `NSView` or `UIView` that `View` is trying to render into.  After figuring out how big that underlying AppKit/UIKit view has to be, and where it is to be positioned, (ie, after applying its layout constraints), it simply passes its bounds to `CustomShape`'s `path(in:)` to get a `Path`, which I'm sure is ultimately just a `struct` wrapper for a `CGPath`.

Your `CustomSHAPE` on the other hand does not conform to `Shape`.  It conforms to a different protocol, `SHAPE`.  `View` doesn't know anything about `SHAPE`, so it can't do anything with it.  All it knows is that it conforms to `View`, so it has to restrict what it does with `CustomSHAPE` to only the things the `View` protocol guarantees.

Basically your custom shapes need to conform to SwiftUI's protocols for `SwiftUI` to know how to use them.

Now, if you write your own generic `View` that wraps `SHAPE` instances, maybe you could implement your own forwarding to `SHAPE`'s `path(in:)` method, but I'm not sure off the top of my head how to implement it in a way that properly hooks into SwiftUI's rendering.

Comment: My basic question is about finding the mechanism of auto grab functionality, **SHAPE** is not even important for me, it is a use case where could be useful, there for I am testing and trying to make it happen

Comment: It comes down to just conforming to the protocols that SwiftUI provides that implement the functionality you're trying to hook into.  If you were to write a generic library, and you defined a protocol to do some functionality X, your library code expects users of the library to make their types conform to that protocol.  Your code can't know anything about some random protocol they define, even if it provides the same interface, so you have no way of calling it.  That's the same issue with SwiftUI and your SHAPE example.

Comment: I would say I am trying learn about capture all capturable data for my function automatically without asking about them un-like normal function those not work until you feed their parameters and then they would work

Comment: SwiftUI's use of result builders makes it less obvious how to think about it. Maybe a more concrete example would help.   If you want the functionality of `Codable`, then you conform to the `Codable` protocol, right? You can't conform to a `CODABLE` protocol you define that doesn't inherit from `Codable` and then expect `JSONDecoder` to be able to use it.

Comment: `path(in:)` is a normal function.  `View` calls it on `View`s that conform to the `Shape` protocol.   Now, there isa feature of SwiftUI that's kind of like what you describe... several actually. @State, @EnvironmentObject, @ObservedObject, etc... provide access to data your functions can use without it having to be passed into your function.